# Как сделать, что бы поле класса вычислялось каждый раз по-новому при создании экземпляра?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
# ...
class PersonAdvertWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def date_now_to_path(self):
        return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(
        location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 
                              'photos', 
                              date_now_to_path()))
    # ...
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы загружаемые пользователем изображения хранились в директориях вида `.../photos/Год/Месяц/День`.

Это место определяется при помощи поля `file_storage` класса унаследованного от класса `SessionWizardView`.

Как сделать, чтобы каждый раз при создании объекта класса `PersonAdvertWizard` поле класса `file_storage` вычислялось каждый раз по-новому, а не использовалось значение вычисленное при импорте модуля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

class A(object):
    creation = datetime.now()
    def __init__(self):
        A.creation = datetime.now()
    def show(self):
        print A.creation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from aa import A
    a1 = A()
    a1.show()
    time.sleep(3)
    a2 = A()
    a2.show()
    a1.show()
```

Можно попробовать так

```
2016-11-09 22:20:56.947000
2016-11-09 22:20:59.948000
2016-11-09 22:20:59.948000
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы правильно написали, что file_storage это поле класса, и, как поле класса, оно инициализируется один раз при создании класса (тогда, когда модуль импортируется).

Для инициализации этого поля при создании каждого объекта нужно перенести инициализацию в конструктор, то есть сделать это поле не атрибутом класса, а атрибутом объекта.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.file_storage = FileSystemStorage(
    ^^^^
        location = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 
                          'photos', 
                          self.date_now_to_path()))
                          ^^^^
```

Comment: Нет, так не прокатывает: пишет "You need to define 'file_storage' in your wizard view in order to handle file uploads.". Нужен именно аттрибут класса

Comment: А как Вы к нему обращаетесь?

Comment: Зачем атрибут класса при создании объекта?

Comment: Я к нему не обращаюсь. Обращается приложение formtools (это Django)

Comment: Поместите присваивание в классовый метод (работающий от класса), а метод дергайте в конструкторе